# Why does reduce return the root of a pure function?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the zeros of some nonlinear function in a certain range, say $f(x)=x^4+\frac{x}{1-x}-c$. If I enter

```
f[x_] := x^4 + x/(1 - x) - c
Reduce[f[x] == 0 && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals]
```

I get the result

```
c > 0 && x == Root[c + (-1 - c) #1 - #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2]
```

My familiarity with Mathematica is very limited, and I don't really know how to interpret the output. I think the Root[$\cdot$,2] notation is telling me that I need to use the second root of the $\cdot$ expression, which is a pure function here, but what does that mean? What would be the argument passed to the pure function?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html)?

Comment: Yes, there wasn't really an explanation of what the # sign means there either. I was hoping to find some symbolic representation that I could port back to Matlab, where I do most of my calculations

Comment: "some symbolic representation" - it's the root of a fifth-order polynomial, that result's [as good as it gets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Ruffini_theorem).